# How long can vines grow in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When placing a vines, how long can they reach in height and width ?

Does it need to be on a wood or tree and near water too ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notch [recently said](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/113547746585214976) that he will make vines not spread horizontally if there are 4 other vine blocks nearby.  As for height, they will spread infinitely downward.

Currently, vines do not have any particular requirements for growing. ([source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vines)).